# How I turn off the constant notifications or beeping while playing far cry 3?

Tags: far-cry-3

I am not sure what this is but it will constantly beep for as long as you play the game.

I have no idea how to turn it off.  Or even if it's a problem, the video card could be over heating as far as I know.

But always seems to start a few moments after I start Far Cry 3

Here is a video of the problem.

Comment: Disconnect from the internet, as a wild guess I would say that might fix the problem. If it doesn't, look at your task bar and exit programs there one by one until you don't have that beeping sound. If it's not another program running in the background then reinstall the game.

Comment: What type of video card do you have? Have you used any temperature monitoring software to see what temperature it might be getting to? Have you `Alt-Tab`bed out into the OS while the game is running to see if there are any warning messages?

Comment: Doesn't sound like a hardware alarm... it sounds like a wake-up alarm... it almost *has* to be another program.  Post a list of running processes if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Their is a beep allowing on Graphic card software configuration or you can find it on gadgets (GPU Meter) of top right, just click it to disable the sound on all game

*This beep has a use to understand card maximum use!!

you can download GPU Meter by searching on google, there is no rocket science.. these are third party softwares

*http://addgadgets.com/gpu_meter/ (download it from this site)

Comment: There is no GPU Meter gadget in Windows 7. Is it an ATI add-on or something?